# macOS Catalyst configurationForConnecting UISceneSession delegate function not always called on app launch

Tags: swift, macos, mac-catalyst, uiscenedelegate, uiscene

I'm building a macOS Catalyst app with support for multiple windows, which is implemented with the new `UISceneDelegate` set of APIs introduced in iOS 13.

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenesession), as a new window is created, a scene delegate needs to connect to `UISceneSession`, which allows passing information to this session via its `userInfo` property. One way to set `userInfo` before the scene delegate is connected is in this function of `UISceneDelegate`:

```swift
  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession,
    options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions
  ) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    connectingSceneSession.userInfo?["foo"] = "bar"

    return UISceneConfiguration(
      name: "Default Configuration", 
      sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role
    )
  }
```

Looking at [the Developer Reference page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/3197905-application#) for this function, it seems it should be always called on app launch before the main app's scene is set up. Unfortunately, it seems with macOS Catalyst this is not true, but I'm not able to find any documentation or logic for why this function is not always called. In my application, which reuses trivial sample code for `UISceneDelegate`, this function is called randomly about 50% of the time on app launch. This is not great, as it means that randomly 50% of the time app's windows are not properly set up, as required information is not passed in the `userInfo` property of `UISceneSession`.

What is the exact logic for calls to `application(_:configurationForConnecting:options:)` or how to enforce that it is called deterministically on app launch for the first app's scene with macOS Catalyst?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specific to Catalyst - it happens in iOS too. It's to do with window *restoration* versus *creation*. To understand that, see my answer to this more generic question: [Why is UIApplicationDelegate method `application(_:configurationForConnecting:options:)` not called reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63520008/72418)

Answer (score 0):

It could not be called even in iOS, not only Mac Catalyst

Once you have configured `UISceneSession` with particular `persistentIdentifier` UIKit will not call `application(_:configurationForConnecting:options:)` for the session with this `persistentIdentifier` again.

> UIKit calls this method shortly before creating a **new** scene